# Watershed Segmentation in SAGA-GIS

Tags: saga, watershed, image-segmentation, vectorization

I'm trying to segment a topographic map to vectorize it. I'm using the watershed algorithm of SAGA-GIS. It's working fine with polygons, but with roads or contour lines is not working properly.

Here is an example about I refer... the countour lines have differents seed values...

- Anyone knows how could I improve it to obtain clear lines?
- Anyone knows how to remove the square appearance after vectorization?

[image: Contour Lines after Watershed segmentation]